# How do I make my library work with using-directive?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, .net-6.0, using-directives

I created a class library with .Net 6.0 which looks like this:

```
namespace MyLib
{
    public static class MyLib {

        public static void someFunction() { }
    }
}
```

I created a nuget package and added that package to another application. My expectation was that I would put `using MyLib` at the top of a class and then could call `MyLib.someFunction()` in the code. But instead, I always have to call `MyLib.MyLib.someFunction()`, with the `using`-directive doing nothing.

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are the static class and the namespace really share `MyLib` name?

Comment: While the C# compiler does allow it (_stupid, stupid..._), you should always ensure a class's name does not equal its namespace name.

Comment: Namespace same as Classname - I found that this can (and will) cause some trouble.